# With a list of iterators, need to iterate through each completely before moving on to next one

Tags: python, iterator

I have a list of iterators called "last", with each iterator holding 5 values:

```
last = 
[<itertools.islice at 0x10bd29940>,
 <itertools.islice at 0x10cc914c8>,
 <itertools.islice at 0x10b94f7e0>]
```

Each series index (below) also holds 5 dates, and I would like to iterate through each iterator in "last" completely before moving on to the next one. (for each series.index , go through  5 times, then when it moves on to next series.index, loop through next iterator 5 times, etc.

So far I've tried;

```
for date in series.index:
    net = (next(last) - 100) / 100

for date in series.index:
    net = ([next(n) for n in last] - 100) / 100
```

Not sure how to get around this (is there something in itertools?)

Comment: try chaining the iterators using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

Comment: `for it in last: for x in it...`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What is the "next" series index - what is the series index?

Comment: [[x for x in it] for it in last] creates a list, and I need to take them one at a time ,   for example, next(x) for ea iteration in series.index

Comment: The instead of making it a list-comp make it a gen-exp?

Comment: Jon - for each islice in "last" there are 5 values, and there are 5 dates in series index. For each date, I need to extract 1 value from "last"

Comment: would that go outside or inside the for loop Jon

Answer (score 0):

without data, expected output, its hard to guess

but heres a try: (`zip` is useful for "parallel" operations on iterators)

```
last = [range(1000,6000,1000), range(2000,7000,1000), range(3000,8000,1000)]

series =[range(1,6,1), range(2,7,1), range(3,8,1)]

[[*zip(srs, map(lambda x: (x - 100) / 100, ls))] for srs, ls in zip(series, last)]

[[(1, 9.0), (2, 19.0), (3, 29.0), (4, 39.0), (5, 49.0)],
 [(2, 19.0), (3, 29.0), (4, 39.0), (5, 49.0), (6, 59.0)],
 [(3, 29.0), (4, 39.0), (5, 49.0), (6, 59.0), (7, 69.0)]]
```